# How can I push down the footer of my page so that it always wraps to the left?

Tags: html, css

I made a page that has a menu on the left, some content on the rest of the page and a footer on the bottom.

Everything works perfectly **if I have a big wall of text as content**, because that will **push the footer** down and it will make the footer wrap to the left around the menu. This way, everything looks and works exactly as I want it.

However, when the content is just a **small paragraph**, the footer is not pushed enough and it just hangs to the right of the menu, just like the content.

Here's an SSCCE of my problem:

```css
* {
 border:0;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

#menu-box {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 120px;
}

#menu-box .menu-category {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

#menu-box .menu-item {
    padding-left: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu-box .menu-item a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu-box .menu-item a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#menu-box .selected {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
}

#content
{
 margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 140px;
}

#footer {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #909090;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
<body>

    <div id="menu-box">
        <div class="menu-category">
            <span>Section 1</span>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><span class="menu-item"><a href="index.php">Item 1</a></span></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="menu-category">
            <span>Section 2</span>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><span class="menu-item selected">&gt; Item 2 &lt;</span></li>
            <li><span class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 3</a></span></li>
            <li><span class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 4</a></span></li>
            <li><span class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 5</a></span></li>
            <li><span class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 6</a></span></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="menu-category">
            <span>Section 3</span>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><span class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 7</a></span></li>
            <li><span class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 8</a></span></li>
            <li><span class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 9</a></span></li>
            <li><span class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 10</a></span></li>
            <li><span class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 11</a></span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<div id="content">
   
    <p>Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here.</p>
    <p>Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here.</p>
</div>

<div id="footer">
            
   This is / should be the footer of the site
   <br />
   But it's too high and too much to the right of the page because the content is not sufficient to make it go UNDER the menu
            
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way I can **make the footer be below the menu-box** no matter how much content there is on the page ?

Thanks.

PS: I do have jQuery and jQueryUI on this site, so if these libraries can provide some sort of solution, I can use it.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for what is commonly called a "sticky footer". Here's an example using Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/ - is that similar to what you're after?

Comment: What he wants is even so much simpler. He just wants to avoid the footer floating around the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `clear: left;` to the footer.

```css
* {
 border:0;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

#menu-box {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 120px;
}

#menu-box .menu-category {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

#menu-box .menu-item {
    padding-left: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu-box .menu-item a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu-box .menu-item a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#menu-box .selected {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
}

#content
{
 margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 140px;
}

#footer {
 clear: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #909090;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
<body>

    <div id="menu-box">
        <div class="menu-category">
            <span>Section 1</span>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><span class="menu-item"><a href="index.php">Item 1</a></span></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="menu-category">
            <span>Section 2</span>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><span class="menu-item selected">&gt; Item 2 &lt;</span></li>
            <li><span class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 3</a></span></li>
            <li><span class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 4</a></span></li>
            <li><span class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 5</a></span></li>
            <li><span class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 6</a></span></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="menu-category">
            <span>Section 3</span>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><span class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 7</a></span></li>
            <li><span class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 8</a></span></li>
            <li><span class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 9</a></span></li>
            <li><span class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 10</a></span></li>
            <li><span class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 11</a></span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<div id="content">
   
    <p>Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here.</p>
    <p>Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here.</p>
</div>

<div id="footer">
            
   This is / should be the footer of the site
   <br />
   But it's too high and too much to the right of the page because the content is not sufficient to make it go UNDER the menu
            
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#footer {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #909090;
  clear:both;
}
```

This is what you need. Edit the #footer in your css, and update it with `clear:both;`. That would make it render below all the floated elements, in this case the left menu.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add `<br style="clear:both">` before `<div id="footer">`

```css
* {
 border:0;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

#menu-box {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 120px;
}

#menu-box .menu-category {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

#menu-box .menu-item {
    padding-left: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu-box .menu-item a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu-box .menu-item a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#menu-box .selected {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
}

#content
{
 margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 140px;
}

#footer {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #909090;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
<body>

    <div id="menu-box">
        <div class="menu-category">
            <span>Section 1</span>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><span class="menu-item"><a href="index.php">Item 1</a></span></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="menu-category">
            <span>Section 2</span>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><span class="menu-item selected">&gt; Item 2 &lt;</span></li>
            <li><span class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 3</a></span></li>
            <li><span class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 4</a></span></li>
            <li><span class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 5</a></span></li>
            <li><span class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 6</a></span></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="menu-category">
            <span>Section 3</span>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><span class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 7</a></span></li>
            <li><span class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 8</a></span></li>
            <li><span class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 9</a></span></li>
            <li><span class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 10</a></span></li>
            <li><span class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item 11</a></span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<div id="content">
   
    <p>Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here.</p>
    <p>Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here. Some content here.</p>
</div>
<br style="clear:both">

<div id="footer">
            
   This is / should be the footer of the site
   <br />
   But it's too high and too much to the right of the page because the content is not sufficient to make it go UNDER the menu
            
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No need to add unnecessary markup here. Adding `clear: left;` to the `#footer` clears the floating menu and does the trick.